# How to set <body> size? (Height & Width)

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could set up the body tag in CSS so that the "max-height" of the body where I'm adding new elements is right below the navbar (which is 100% x 35px) so that when I add new elements for example it automatically loads in the defined area instead of where it usually does because now there's the navbar (look top left corner).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
body {
      min-height: calc(75vh - 50px);
      width: 100%
}
```

Comment: thank you this gave me more control over the height compared to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vh postfix on height.

> Represents a percentage of the height of the viewport's initial containing block. 1vh is 1% of the viewport height. For example, if the viewport height is 300px, then a value of 70vh on a property will be 210px.

```
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}
```